How a dynamic Select Component should work?
I'm questioning my understanding of how a dynamic Selector component should work (by dynamic, I mean that I can add/delete/update its options)
I have a basic form to add options to, like below. At the creation, value = label:
options: [ value: String, label: String}]

So I start creating two options. Lets say :
const options: [{ label: 'Google', value: 'Google'}, {label: 'Facebook', value: 'Facebook'}]


Then I update the first option label's let's say that Google => New Label Google. So I will have.
const options: [{ label: 'New Label Google', value: 'Google'}, {label: 'Facebook', value: 'Facebook'}]

Now I want to add an new option. In order to show my point, I will create :
const newOption = {value : 'Google', label : 'Google'}

const newOptions: [...options, newOption]

Notice here that I have three different labels, but I have doubled values, even if I block the creation of doubled labels.
How can I assure that I will always have unique values in my options ?
I have a feeling that I'm overthinking this process, but it would be nice to have another opinion.
EDIT : Of course that, I can block the user from creating a new option with an label that already exists in the set of 'values', but this would be strange because the front-end user has no knowledge about values, as he only sees 'labels'.
